# Using CoffeeScript to select default value for select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I'm trying to set a default value of a select box. Here is my current failed attempt.

```
  $("#event_location_country").on "load", () ->
    $(this).val("US")
```

## Html

```
  <%= f.select :location_country, countries, {}, class: "form-control", required: true %>
  <%= f.label :location_country, class: "form-note" %>
```

Here is the html is the console:

```
<option value="US">United States</option>
```

Obviously all the other countries of the world but I want the US to be the default on page load. Also. Is there in easier way to do this with just html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<option value="US" selected>United States</option>
```